# Turn nav into modal and fill entire screen

Tags: html, css

I have a nav that I want to turn into a modal using a CSS class toggled by javascript. The thing is, because it's a complex layout I can't change the HTML structure I have currently, since this is only for mobiles using mediaquery.

The idea is that the nav looks a certain way (i.e, without the modal class applied) but I will integrate a button which applies the class "modal" to the nav tag, to make the nav tag into a modal box which covers the whole screen.

Here is my code showing how it will look with the nav with the modal class applied: https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/fxnzdofh/3/.

Here is my question / issue. Keeping the same HTML structure, how can I change the modal css to make the blue box from the very top left of the screen, and not instead under the green header bar. The end result is the entire screen blue from corner to corner.

This is the code I tried but didn't give me the result I wanted:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Keeping the same HTML structure, how can I change the modal css to make the blue box from the very top left of the screen?*

You forgot to add `top` and `left` to position it from the `top`:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mfjsomca/**